# Xampp's icon on taskbar is not triggering pop up on click

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, taskbar, troubleshooting

I recently installed the Wampp 64 bit software for my PC and after installation when I launch it, it runs properly and the logo of wampp dashboard appears on the taskbar.

[image]

It says “all services running” on hover and is green (indicating all Apache, SQL and PHP are active). However, the usual pop-up/dashboard which appears when you right click does not appear. It is completely unresponsive. Any permanent workaround before I reinstall?

Comment: Xampp or Wamp? These are two different programs.

Comment: Wamp , my bad. I shall edit the question.